# CVDisplayLink constant outputTime value

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, opengl, vsync

I'm writing this post in case anyone else is having the same issue I've been having with the lack of documentation for the CVDisplayLink API.

**Intro:**

In my CVDisplayLink code I've been using the following code to obtain the deltaSeconds value between calls to its callback:

```
float deltaTime = 1.0 / (outputTime->rateScalar * (float)outputTime->videoTimeScale / (float)outputTime->videoRefreshPeriod);
```

It seems like this line of code is widely used across different apps & engines.

**The issue:**

While running my OpenGL app I've noticed that this value is now constant (`0.016669` to be precise).  I haven't made any big changes to account for this change of behaviour, other than using Mavericks and the new development tools.

Finding the cause has been a lost cause so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what I believe is a good way to calculate the deltaSeconds between frames by using the following alternative code:

```
double deltaSeconds = (outputTime->videoTime - self.previousOutputVideoTime) / (double)outputTime->videoTimeScale;
self.previousOutputVideoTime = outputTime->videoTime;
```